# Table Layout using CSS

Tags: css

I was trying to use table layout with my **div**. Everything is fine with my config. But, there is a problem with setting min-width. I was trying to use this in forms. Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dheyvendaran/cfGWG/4/).

When, the **divleft** label size gets increases, then it should not wrap to the next line until the maindiv width reaches the limit. so it means setting left div min-width as 25% and if the left div content grows, then it should extend the width to fit to the content until it reaches main div width. Pls suggest me how can i do this.

**Css Code**

```
.divmain
{
display: table-row;
padding: 12px;
}
.divleft
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 1px;
width: 25%;
}
.divright
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: tip : why you add `.divmain` before each CSS property? remove that

Answer (score 2):

add two property

```
.divmain { width:100% }

.divleft { min-width: 25%; }
```

Note : I also have changed your CSS declaration : [`see the  DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/cfGWG/2/)

#### Update

Note: you have missed `divright` class on first row in your updated demo. now see

```
.divleft
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1px;
    min-width: 35%;
}
.divright
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/cfGWG/5/)

Comment: Seems min-width for divleft is not working. When the labels are too small, the divleft should use min-width as 25% to allow start of divright elements.

Comment: I have to provide a min-width for divleft element (say 25%). If my divleft element label is so small like No., Name, Dept then also divleft should take min-width as 25%. see the demo again. I updated.